# Why is it so difficult to find Skewes' number?

Tags: number-theory, soft-question, prime-numbers

**Warning: naïve question ahead!**

Littlewood proved in 1914 that there exists a number $n\in\mathbb{N}$ (called *Skewes' number*) such that:

$$
\pi(n) > \operatorname{li}(n).
$$

It is conjectured that $n$ is a huge number, recent analysis suggests $n\approx e^{727.951}$. Since then, researchers have worked to find lower and upper bounds for $n$. Currently it is held that:

$$
10^{19}<n<e^{727.951}.
$$

Why is it that researchers are trying to improve these bounds instead of finding an exact value? Since $\pi(n) \sim \frac{n}{\ln(n)}$ for very large numbers (i.e. > $10^{19}$), we have:

$$
\frac{n}{\ln(n)} > \int_0^n \frac{\mathrm dt}{\ln t}. 
$$

And with sufficiently big computing power this should not be too hard to solve. What am I missing?

Comment: what error in thought to point out first. Just because computing is getting better, it's like asking why check if a number is a certain remainder when dividing by 6, before testing for primality, maybe because it cuts the work down by $2\over3$ ... also that gap is still Huge to search $e^{727.951} \approx 10^{316}$

Comment: in other words if to calculate $\pi(n)$ for every last value in a range of $10^{19} $ took a nanosecond it would take about $4.42 \cdot 10^{277}$ millennium to calculate just the $\pi(n)$ values) even if say 70 billion computers were running those calculations that only falls to about $6.32280217\cdot 10^{266}$ millennium.

Comment: For reference, the universe has only existed for less than $10^{27}$ nanoseconds.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee: Perhaps one day when we have a quantum computer. Assuming, that is.

Comment: for further reference if you say yoctoseconds ($10^{-24}$ seconds) instead of nanoseconds you only cut that down to about $6.32280217\cdot10^{251}$ millennium edit: @TitoPiezasIII nope probably not with that big of a range even cutting by about $10^{80}$ ( particles in universe at last check) will only cut this down to $6.32280217\cdot10^{171}$ millennium

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have several problems with this question.  One is that replacing functions with values that are asymptotically equal is not justified.  Consider $f(x)=x^2, g(x)=x^2+\frac 12, h(x)=x^2+\cos x$.  They are all asymptotically $x^2$ but comparing them depends on the non-leading terms.  Second, $\operatorname{li}(n)$ is a much better approximation to $\pi(n)$ than $\frac n{\ln (n)}$.  Skewes' number depends on the comparison between $\pi(n)$ and $\operatorname{li}(n)$.  $\frac n{\log n}$ is not involved.  Your final inequality is false for $n \gt 3.847$  Finally, you seem to expect that $10^{19}$ or Skewes' number is large enough for asymptotics to have taken hold.  It would not be hard to construct an example where this fails.  We could ask for what $n$ does $10^{-6}\log (\log(n))$ exceed $1$.  It obviously does eventually, but for *much* larger values than we are talking about here.

Comment: This reminds me of a professor's quip that, for all practical purposes, $\log(\log(\log(x)))$ is bounded above by $6$.

Answer (score 0):

A  practical answer is this.  The current best estimate of the first Skewes number is ${SK}_{1} = 1.397162914 \times 10^{316}$.  Now computing on Mathematica the logarithmic integral at this value takes a fraction of a second.  However the efforts in computing the exact value of the prime counting function at the value of $10^27$ results in a paper (2015 by David Baugh and Kim Walisch) Walisch, Kim (September 6, 2015). "New confirmed pi(10^27) prime counting function record". Mersenne Forum.  So at this point no one can compute the exact value of the prime counting function near the first Skewes number within a reasonable amount of time.  This is why say lets sprinkle random numbers near Skewes first number, compute the values and see if we 'hit" a point where the prime count is larger than the logarithmic integral has not occurred.

Comment: To see the computational effort for this last case, this is the partial 2015 blog posting of the above results:
 
Sep 2015

Default New confirmed pi(10^27), pi(10^28) prime counting function records
I am happy to announce that David Baugh and I have computed the number
of primes below 10^27, the result is:

pi(10^27) = 16,352,460,426,841,680,446,427,399

The computation took
23.03 CPU core years and the peak memory usage was 235 gigabytes.

Regards,
Kim Walisch